# How to change a color of an html ouput based on its values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have wrote a small html to display some results.

The results Can be `SUCCESS`, `Failure` and `Still Failing`. I'm looking for a way to output this based in color. So for `SUCCESS` the color should be green , `Failure` -> red and `Still Failing` -> red

I checked for an answer and most are using JavaScript or jQuery but I have no idea how to implement it. I tried many different ideas but it didn't work.

Is there some if condition statement that can take care of this?

```
    <body leftmargin="8" marginwidth="0" topmargin="8" marginheight="4" offset="0">
        <table width="95%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <tr>
                <td>(Automatic email, DO NOT REPLY)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>
                        <font color="#039b10">Build result - SUCCESS</font>
                    </h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: how are you generating the html?

Comment: The `<font>` element doesn't exist anymore. Use CSS. And you forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried.

Comment: I have no experience on CSS , JS or JQ , can you please the full code?

Answer (score 0):

The  tag you are using has long been deprecated in favour of using css classes. You should give your h2 a class of success or failure and then assign an appropriate colour to the css class.

If you are new to css, a guide such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS should get you started

Answer (score 0):

You can check in this code snip. Based on the value we can change CSS.

In this code when will you type **success** in small then you will see the green background otherwise red background.

```js
$('#inputButton').click(function(){
  var inputVal = $('#inputText').val();
  if(inputVal == 'success'){
    $('#message').removeClass('red');
    $('#message').addClass('green');
  } else {
    $('#message').removeClass('green');
    $('#message').addClass('red');
  }

});
```

```css
.green{
background : green;
}
.red{
background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputText" />
<input type="button" id="inputButton" value="Check" />
<div id="message">Message</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class to a `font` tag, and based on your result, you can change the class color.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a div for results:

```
<div id='build_results'></div>
```

Now suppose you have the following script:

```
<script>
//you mention using jquery, so we will assume that...
function GetResultsFromWork() {
  //Do work
  return someValOfWorkResults;
}    

function someScript(){
  var workResults = GetResultsFromWork();
  setBuildResponseMessage(workResults);  
}

function setBuildResponseMessage(results) {
  switch(results) {
    case 'failure':
    case 'failure_again':
      $('#build_results')
        .removeAttr('class')
        .addClass('buildFailure')
        .text('Failure!');
    case 'success':
    default:
      $('#build_results')
        .removeAttr('class')
        .addClass('buildSuccess')
        .text('Success!');
      break;
  }
}
</script>
```

And suppose you had the following styles for css:

```
<style>
.buildFailure {
  color:red;
}

.buildSuccess {
  color:green;
}
</style>
```

Rough idea of what should work. I haven't written javascript in a few, but offhand it should run fine. That is the basic premise